# Get the key name from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have got a JSON string:

```
 var json = {
"result": [{
    "ID": "9",
    "user_name": "Mr Smith",
"authormeta": {
    "session_token": {
    "5633543626268661e7": {
            "expiration": 1423329065
        }
    }
}
}]
}

 $('p').append(json.result[0].ID + ' | ' + json.result[0].user_name + ' | ' + json.result[0].authormeta.session_tokens + ' | ' + json.result[0].authormeta.session_tokens.expiration);
```

And successfully getting `json.result[0].ID + json.result[0].user_name` but having a problem of getting dynamically changed key name - `json.result[0].authormeta.session_tokens` and value of the expiration.

It should look like in html: `9 | Mr Smith | 5633543626268661e7 | 1423329065`

My demo JSFIDDLE is here http://jsfiddle.net/gegjsb6w/2/

Can any body please help me to amend the JSFIDDLE to get the info I need. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You call it `session_token` and reference it as `session_tokens`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var sessionKey = Object.keys(json.result[0].authormeta.session_token).pop(),
    session    = json.result[0].authormeta.session_token[sessionKey];

$('p').append(json.result[0].ID + ' ' + json.result[0].user_name + sessionKey + ' ' + session.expiration);
```

1. In JSON Object there is `session_token` but no `session_tokens`.
2. To get properties `expiration` and `login` you need to get key ("`5633543626268661e7`") you can get it dynamically using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (As in my example)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gegjsb6w/10/)